# Wordpress: Permalinks link to old names

Tags: permalinks

I'm trying to activate permalinks on my Wordpress installation.

When I activate them my menu links point to page names that have changed sometime ago which result in a 404. I don't really understand how I can configure this. When I edit the menu in the menu settings the names are the current ones.

I use qtranslate. Can this be the source of the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. The box to edit the title had been invisible. I made it visible with the according  checkbox in the options bar on the top.